# C# using stored procedure : how can I use .FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I wrote two functions, function #1 gets data from database based on key, function #2 calls the first function if data is present, then it deletes the record.

But when data is not available, then also its enter in if condition

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int Key)
{
      Employee employee = new Employee();

      if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
      {
          con.Open();
      }

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetById", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Key);

      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      if (rdr.HasRows == true)
      {
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
              employee.Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Emp_Id"]);
              employee.EmpName = rdr[("EmpName")].ToString();

              if (!Convert.IsDBNull(rdr[("Cnt_Id")]))
              {
                  employee.Cnt_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Cnt_Id"]);
              }
```

Here I'm calling `GetEmployee()` in `DeleteById(int key)`

```
public void DeleteById(int Id)
{
     var x = GetEmployee(Id);

     if (x != null)
     {
     }
}
```

Problem is when id is not present in the database, the code still enters the `If` condition

Comment: Why *load* the employee record when you want to delete it? Just write a SQL query or stored procedure that *deletes* the matching record. You don't need LINQ to return the first entry either. Just *don't* use a `while` loop. Call `Read()` once and read the fields. If you want to delete the record *and* retrieve the deleted data add an `OUTPUT` clause to the `DELETE` statement

Comment: its good but i need to use re-usability function

Comment: How is reusability affected in this case? YOu *don't* have any kind of reusability right now. You have one inappropriate stored procedure that only works with one table. Write an *appropriate* stored procedure.

Comment: If you want reusability I'd suggest you check a micro ORM like Dapper.NET. You could replace all this code with a single line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks a lot for ur iformation

Comment: as a solution to the current issue, you would set the employee to before assigning the row from the db

Comment: and what does your SP return when there are no rows?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you get function you have this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

I assume in the end of the function you have something like

```
return employee;
```

That is why x is never null.
You can do a

```
if(x.Id != null)
```

because when no emplyee is in de the db, id never gets a value.

Comment: Or better initialize it to null and only create the object when you actually have an object. Then the null check works and makes much more sense.

Comment: @Chris Is that allowed to do a Employee employee = null? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean exactly that. It assumes that Employee isn't a struct (but it really shouldn't be). If an entity exists it is much better represented by null than as an object with no properties set on it. As demonstrated by the later code it makes much more sense to do test `foo==null` to see if something doesn't exist than to have to check a property on that object. Also if `Id` is something like an `int` then it will never be null so that check wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didnt know that. I will keep this in mind when doing my next c# project.

Answer (score 1):

Its because it won't be null in you code so inside `GetEmployee` do the following:

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int Key)
{
      //Employee employee = new Employee();//this will make the condition always true
      Employee employee = null;//Replace it with this to start with null value
      if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
      {
          con.Open();
      }
```

Then inside the `while` it will be like this :

```
 while (rdr.Read())
 {
   employee = new Employee();//add this 
   employee.Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Emp_Id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no record then you need to return null from "GetEmployee()" method..For that you can do this..

**Answer 1)**

```
      List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetById", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Key);

      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      if (rdr.HasRows == true)
      {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
        employee.Add(new Employee{
        Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Emp_Id"]),
        EmpName = rdr[("EmpName")].ToString()
           });
        }
     }
```

and while returning write this..

```
return employee.FirstOrDefault();
```

Here FirstOrDefault() method will return single Employee object if there is data otherwise returns null...

**Answer 2)**

```
  Employee employee = new Employee();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetById", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Key);

  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  if (rdr.HasRows == true)
  {
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
       employee.Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Emp_Id"]);
       employee.EmpName = rdr[("EmpName")].ToString();
    }
 }
 else
 {
   return null;
 }

return employee;
```

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail why you are creating a list and also how you would alter the code that actually writes to employee? Obviosuly the existing code will no longer work if `employee` is a `List<Employee>` rather than an `Employee`....

Comment: i just updated the answer, even though it is List at the end it is returning the single Employee object.., and he is expecting to return null if there is no data in Employee object , So i used "FirstOrDefault" method..

Comment: I think you are missing a `new Employee` in your while loop. Also I am still confused as to what the benefit of putting this employee into a list and then getting it out again over just having an employee that is either null or an object is.

Comment: yes updated...and your right chris, but as i said he is expecting to get null so i suggested this...

Comment: My point is that creating a list and using `FirstOrDefault` is not a good way to get null. If you want a null you can just use `null`. eg `return null;` or `Employee employee = null;`. Your code seems to just be complicated and confusing.

Comment: your right..i updated answer2 ..but it depends on various factors that which  one we use over other..and there are so many other ways to achieve same thing ..but may be it's all about perspectives and requirements...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157116/discussion-between-jilani-pasha-and-chris).